# Why dosn't Octave textscan skip headerlines?

Tags: octave, textscan

I am using Octave 4.0.0 on Windows and have problems when using `textscan` on text data downloaded from the internet. These data have the following format on the internet:

`quote_date;paper;exch;open;high;low;close;volume;value
20150605;OTS;Oslo Børs;5.88;5.88;5.88;5.88;5000;29400
20150604;OTS;Oslo Børs;5.50;5.50;5.50;5.50;3728;20504
20150603;OTS;Oslo Børs;5.69;5.70;5.69;5.70;1000;5694
20150601;OTS;Oslo Børs;5.40;5.73;5.30;5.73;4575;24633
20150529;OTS;Oslo Børs;5.40;5.40;5.39;5.40;20197;109033`

I am not shure what the end-of-line charachter is in the original data set, but when I copy and paste them into 'Notepad+' the end-of-line characters are CR,LF.

Below I use `urlread` to read the  data from the url address `a` into a string `x`:

`a = 'http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/paperhistory.php?paper=OTS.OSE&csv_format=sdv';`
`x = urlread(a);`

Then I want to use `textscan` to convert the string `x` into a vector with header strings and a data vector per header string.

The conversion into a vector with header strings goes well
`h = textscan(x,['%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s'],1,'delimiter',';');`

This produces a cell array with the nine header text strings, as I wanted. However, when trying to read the rest of the data (skipping the first header line) with the following code:

`y = textscan(x,'%d %s %s %f %f %f %f %d %d','headerlines',1,'delimiter',';');`

I get this warning from Octave:

`>> y = textscan(x,'%d %s %s %f %f %f %f %d %d','headerlines',1,'delimiter',';');`
`warning: textscan: 'headerlines' ignored when reading from strings`
`warning: called from`
`textscan at line 181 column 7`
`warning: strread: unknown property 'headerlines'`

So `textscan` does not understand `headerlines`. This applies whether I write `headerlines`, `Headerlines`, or `HeaderLines`.

Why doesn't `textscan` understand the property `headerlines` even thought this property is defined in the `textscan` help menu?